# Clustering error while using BOW to get the vocabulary of the images

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection, sift

```
void SceneRecognition::BowRepresentation()
{
    Mat dstGray2;
    //Folder path is written and file names are taken according to that.
    vector <String> fileNames;
    String folder("airCond/Train/*.jpg");
    glob(folder, fileNames,false);
    //File names are checked.
    for (auto t : fileNames)
    {
        cout << t << endl;
    }
    
    //Object is opened.
    Ptr<SiftFeatureDetector> detector;

    //Gray image holder is opened.
    Mat dst, dstGray;

    //Detector is created.
    detector = SiftFeatureDetector::create();

    //Keypoint vector is created.
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

    //Object is opened.
    Mat Desp;
    Ptr<SiftDescriptorExtractor> extractor;
    //Extractor is created.
    extractor = SiftDescriptorExtractor::create();
    Mat training_descriptors(1, extractor->descriptorSize(), extractor->descriptorType());
    // Image matrices are read in a loop.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fileNames.size(); i++)
    {
        Mat im = imread(fileNames[i]);
        //Image is converted to gray.
        cvtColor(im, dstGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        detector->detect(dstGray, keypoints);
        //Descriptors are extracted.
        extractor->compute(dstGray, keypoints, Desp);
        training_descriptors.push_back(Desp);
    }
    cout << training_descriptors.size << endl;
    /*Number of clusters are chosen as 1000.*/
    //TermCriteria tc(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER + TermCriteria::EPS, 10, 0.001);
    //int retries = 1;
    //int flags = KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;
    BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(100);
    bowTrainer.add(training_descriptors);
    //Created descriptors are added.
    cout << "a" << endl;
    //Vocabulary is created by k-means clustering.
    Mat vocabulary = bowTrainer.cluster();
}
```

When I run my code I get an error as followed: OpenCV(4.5.5) Error: Iterations do not converge (kmeans: can't update cluster center (check input for huge or NaN values)) in cv::generateCentersPP, file C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\openncvv\opencv-4.5.5\modules\core\src\kmeans.cpp, line 147

I tried different approaches but couldn't come up with an answer. Any suggestions?
[One row of an input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Mzl.png)

One of the image size is 75*144. Should I change something when I taking the image as input ?

Comment: did you check the input for huge or NaN values? show us the input

Comment: I checked it right now and u're right I missed out some of the entries. Thank you!